# Flow to Count Number of Tasks on the Lead Record

Tags: recordtriggeredflow

new to flows and hope you can help. Need a flow to update the "Task Count" number on lead record when a new task is created.

- On a Lead object created a custom field "Task Count" with number data type to count the total number of tasks on a lead record. On the lead record created a few tasks.
- Created Record Triggered flow on the Task object
- Decision element search for Lead record
- If found, Update records element updates the Lead record.
- Created a variable with data type number.
- The flow finds the Lead record with the tasks created but doesn't update the "Task Count" field.
  What is missing? Thank you!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running the flow in [debug mode](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/flow-testing-and-distribution/make-sure-your-flow-works)?

Comment: @identigral Yes, debugged multiple times, no debug error. The first screenshot is from the debug screen

Comment: Your screenshot shows that `TaskCountVar` is null and it's unclear where/how the value of `TaskCountVar` is set. Recommend you look into [DLRS](https://github.com/SFDO-Community/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries)

Comment: Thank you so much!